# Upload Api on server (I used #cloudinary #mongobd #strapicms to create and deploy my API)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, strapi, cloudinary

Please help me to upload my api in someone's server. I have used mongodb database,strapi cms,heruko for pass and cloudinary. But I am unable to upload it in server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What error do you receive, and using what code? Can you share the details, please?